# I enable mssql in IIS, but I can't connect sql server. How to fix it

Tags: php, iis-8

I can not connect Sql Server 2012 with mssql extension. Please help me to fix it. I Got this message in error log.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\PHP\v5.2.17\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module
>   could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

[image: Error on Browser]

[image: IIS8 PHP Manager (PHP v5.2.17)]

Thanks

Comment: Does `'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.2.17\ext\php_mssql.dll` exist?

Comment: I have already.

Comment: have already what? The error is pretty clear. Either the file doesn't exist, is not readable, or corrupt.